# How to get Interface Builder name from id

Tags: objective-c, iphone

If I name a widget in Interface Builder, and then I write a method that receives click events on that button:

```
- (IBAction)btnTouchDown:(id)sender
{
  // how can you identify the button here,
  // if several different buttons map
  // their "Touch" event to this same function?
  // I know you can look at its text but that seems really clumsy
  // can I somehow get its INTERFACE BUILDER NAME?

  // I named each uniquely in interface builder,
  // under "Identity"/"Name"
  // Or is my only recourse to tie EACH BUTTON to its own handler function?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the button in interface builder, press CMD+2 (Or in info dialog, second tab) and drag the circle from **Touch up inside** to **File's Owner** from the yourView.xib window and then it'll let you select one of the methods which has the `- (IBAction) method:(id)sender` signature. Choose the one you want to associate with that button :)

You say you don't want to make a method for each button, but actually that is the best way in my opinion, rather than having one huge monolithic method which handles each of the buttons and checks each time to see which one of them it is. Using the process I mentioned above, you can specifically tie a handler method to a particular button, keeping things nice, tidy, and logical.

If you really want to do that though, you can also test for the **tag number**.

Comment: But I want to use _the same_ function to handle _all_ the buttons.  can't I use an IF statement inside my event handler and check "which button was pressed" that way?

Comment: I added that in my latest edit. You might think that's a straightforward approach, but it's much easier if you have different methods handling different logical paths. That way one big function won't get screwed up by a bug of one of the button's handler branches. It's a lot more maintainable. But like I said, if you really want to, check the tag attribute. You're right about checking for the text being clumsy (and unnecessarily expensive), but the same can be said about having one big method that handles ALL of your buttons.

Comment: please super bold the words __tag number__ :D

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the button as an instance variable in your view controller and then use the IBOutlet pragma to make it known to IB.  So for example you would do this in your view controller:

```
UIButton IBOutlet *mybutton;
```

After defining it like this it will show up in your IB connections where you can associate it with the appropriate button

Comment: It's IBOutlet UIButton *mybutton; I think.

Comment: actually the order  doesn't matter as with most modifiers